# Irreducible character of degree $n$ is $|\chi(g)|=n$ for every element in the center

Tags: representation-theory, characters

G is a finite group. Let $\chi$ be an irreducible character of degree $n$ (that is $\chi(1)=n$). Show that $|\chi(g)|=n$ for every element in $Z(G)$.

I am basically asking to prove that $Z(G)\subseteq\ker \chi$ which can be shown by using Schur's Lemma but I would like to know if there can be a proof without it. Perhaps it could be fully utilising the orthogonality relations or some other properties of the character $\chi$.

Comment: Hint: use an orthogonality relation and notice that $\chi(1)\geq |\chi(g)|$

Comment: I still don't see it can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By orthogonality you have $\sum_{i=1}^s|\chi_i(g)|^2=|C(g)|$ summing over irreducible characters where $C(g)=\{x \in G:xg=gx\}$. Since $g\in Z(G)$ you have $C(g)=G$ and thus $\sum_{i=1}^s|\chi_i(g)|^2=|G|=\sum_{i=1}^s\chi_i(1)^2 \implies \sum_{i=1}^s(\chi_i(1)^2-|\chi_i(g)|^2)=0$. Now since $\chi_i(1)\geq{}|\chi_i(g)|$ we have $\chi_i(1)^2-|\chi_i(g)|^2\geq 0$ forcing $\chi_i(1)^2=|\chi_i(g)|^2$ and thus $\chi_i(1)=|\chi_i(g)|$.

Comment: Not quite right: you are summing over all irreducible characters, not conjugacy classes, and secondly, $|\chi(g)| \geq 1$ is not true ($\chi(g)$ can be $0$). But you only need $|\chi(g)| \leq \chi(1)$, so no worries.

Comment: Yes indeed thank you for both corrections, I meant to write that both are natural numbers. I really oversaw the conjugacy class part, perhaps I was thinking about the other orthogonality relation at the time

Comment: Be careful, $|\chi(g)|$ does not have to be a natural number. The difference $\chi(1)^2-|\chi(g)|^2$ is a non-negative *real* number, that suffices. I like your solution by the way and +1-ed you!

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments, I was impulsive with the answer, hopefully OP noticed the edits

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης Can you explain why $\chi(1)^2-|\chi(g)|^2$?